# MVC Architecture/SoC: Should Controller Initiate DB Transaction?

Tags: mysql, model-view-controller, transactions, separation-of-concerns

I have a Controller handling form inputs which affect two separate DB tables handled by their respective Models. If there is a is an issue recording data in either of these tables, I want the request to fail and no records should be inserted/updated.

It would be easy to have my Controller initiate a DB Transaction, but would this be considered bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to validate all fields in the controller, and then if all validations passed you trigger your db transaction into the corresponding model. In my experience it is a better practice than making all directly in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to get varying responses on this. I would say all depends on where you are placing your business logic. In a cqrs pattern this would be handled quite differently than the repository'esque pattern. Do you create your own models?